# How do I list fonts that are available to VSCode on macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, fonts

So, I have a patched version of Fira Code that I use in Terminal.app, which knows it by the name "Fira Code Regular Nerd Font Complete". If I enter that name in the editor font settings of VSCode it is clearly unrecognized.

How do I list fonts known to VSCode, and if it is missing altogether, what do I need to do to install it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To list the fonts that are available, run the following command in the terminal:

```
system_profiler -json SPFontsDataType | grep \"family | sort | uniq
```

This will show the name you need to supply to VSCode to use the font.

Any font that is activated on the Mac will be available to VSCode. I am using a patched font, and by applying the name that is shown using the command above, I was able to use it in VSCode.

Comment: This comment and code snippet were exactly what I needed -- thanks!!!